# name of an attribute in the datacontext (linq to sql)

Tags: linq-to-sql

I am using LINQ to SQL in Visual Studio 2010 with C#.

I have the following table with attributes such as:

```
table abacus(
   a0 float
   a1 float
   a2 float
   .....)
```

Can I retrieve the second attribute (`a1`) and return a string value with a command from the `DataContext` ?

I'm thinking of something like `cxt.ABACUSs.GetAttribut(2)` -> `a1`.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure whether I understand what you're looking for.....

To select a row from your table, use:

```
var row = ctx.ABACUSs.FirstOrDefault(a => a.ID = 5); // or whatever
```

Then, when you have that element, you can read its properties - the column `a1` should be turned into a property `a1` on that object:

```
// check for != null just to be safe....
if(row != null)
{
   var yourResult = row.a1;
}
```

Tables are always organized into rows and columns - you first need to select a row in Linq-to-SQL, turn that into an object, and then you can inspect / read the properties on that object (that correspond to the columns of your table).

Since you get back objects (instances of objects) for each row in Linq-to-SQL, which have properties on them (that you read out by their name), there's no notion of "second attribute" like in a `SqlDataReader`. You cannot get "the second attribute of that row" - you need to know its name.

Or what exactly are you trying to achieve???

Answer (score 0):

My solution will be to build a class to create linq queries.

A `List<string>` will be used to store the names of the attributes which will be used to create a query.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a method that would pick the column to select based on the given index.